# Creating an empty instance of a proto using the typeURL in Go

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, file-descriptor

I'm trying to generate an instance of a proto in Go given an typeURL. Basically what I'm trying to do is schema verification. I have a proto message sent over to a gRPC service, and the message has one field which is protobuf.Any. Now "Any" contains the "typeUrl" which I specified using ***option go_package*** (and I've verified it's correct), and "Value" which is a byte array of the marshalled proto containing the data I need.

What I'm trying to do is when I receive the request on the server side, I'd like to use the "typeUrl" to generate an empty instance of the proto contained in "Value". Here is my code below:

```
func NewProtoInstanceFromAny(any *anypb.Any) (protoreflect.ProtoMessage, error) {
typeURL := any.TypeUrl
// Parse the TypeURL to get the package name and message name
segments := strings.Split(typeURL, "/")
packageName := segments[0]
messageName := segments[1]
println(messageName)
println(packageName)
messageType, _ := protoregistry.GlobalTypes.FindMessageByName(protoreflect.FullName(packageName + "." + messageName))
if messageType == nil {
    print("YES")
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("message %s not found in package %s", messageName, packageName)
}

newValue := messageType.New().Interface()
// Unmarshal the value field of the Any proto into the new message instance
println("HEY")
if err := protojson.Unmarshal(any.Value, newValue); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

print("STRING" + newValue.ProtoReflect().Descriptor().FullName())
```

The issue is that I'm getting a nil for messageType which probably means the file isn't found in the "GlobalRegistry". So I guess my question is, how do I add protos to a registry? I was playing around with *protoregistry.Files{}* but couldn't seem to figure it out. Here's an example I found online but it doesn't work in my case:

```
protoFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("path/to/file/test.proto")
if err != nil {
    print(err)
}

pbSet := new(descriptorpb.FileDescriptorSet)
if err := proto.Unmarshal(protoFile, pbSet); err != nil {
    print(err)
}

pb := pbSet.GetFile()

// Initialize the file descriptor object.
fd, err := protodesc.NewFile(pb[0], protoregistry.GlobalFiles)
if err != nil {
    print(err)
}

// and finally register it.
err = protoregistry.GlobalFiles.RegisterFile(fd)
if err != nil {
    print(err)
}
```

This code panics with index out of range for some reason. Would appreciate some help!